# Live edit In IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, html, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I want to use Live Edit feature and I work in IntelliJ IDEA. I've downloaded necessary plugins (Live Edit, JavaScript Debug, JavaScript and TypeScript). Every time I want to use that feature I need to configure debug configuration manually.

In WebStorm there's one useful feature. We don't need to configure configuration for debugging HTML files every time we need. We just need to choose 'Debug' in popup.

[image: Debug in popup]

But I work in IntelliJ IDEA and I want to use that feature. Is there a way to do that? May be create in some way template?

Comment: Please elaborate: what does not work as in WebStorm? The process actually must be the same.

Comment: In WebStorm all works fine. In WebStorm you can click on 'Debug' in the popup like on the image. But in IDEA I must configure every debug session manually, clicking 'Add configuration'. Is there a way to do that in IDEA like in WebStorm?

Comment: It works for e the same as in WS. Show screenshots of your steps in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: In IDEA I do: (Click near the green arrow in up right corner) -> Edit configuration -> Templates -> JavaScript Debug -> insert path to file html what I want to debug -> Apply -> Select debug configuration -> Ok -> Click on debug in up right corner.

Comment: What I do in WebStorm: Select html file -> right click on it -> click debug in popup.

Comment: `What I do in WebStorm: Select html file -> right click on it -> click debug in popup.` I get this option in IntelliJ IDEA as well. Don't you? Can you record a screencast?

Comment: This is screenshot from Intellij IDEA "https://ibb.co/B2vPCwQ"

Comment: Please select your `index.html` file in IDEA Project tool window, hit `F1` (or whatever shortcut is assigned to **View | Quick Documentation** main menu action) and share a screenshot of the popup that opens.

Comment: "https://ibb.co/4phTyJG" Did you mean that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case when static web assets are located in `resources` directory (instead of the [**Web Resource Directory**, configured in Web facet](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-web-application-support.html#64422463)) the JavaScript Debug action is not available for the file.

Created the [WEB-43750](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43750) request.

Comment: Yes, but what should I do to get that button to my popup?

Comment: Please add step-by-step resolving the problem, and I'll accept the answer. For me resolving is "ctrl+alt+shift+s(Project structure) -> Modules -> unselect in down right part checkbox (resources directory)".

Comment: The only way for using [Live Edit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-editing.html) feature in Spring Boot application for your current IDE version is to create a debug config manually. We’ve implemented a fix on our side and it should be available in the next [EAP build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2020.1+latest+builds) the next week.